# Calculate $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^j (1+\frac{x}{j})^j e^{-\pi x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

My approach:
$$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^j \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x}dx = 
\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x}dx.$$
I'm not sure if I can do the above, but I need it to apply Lebesgue as follows:

I see that $(1+\frac{x}{j})^j \rightarrow e^x$ and $(1+\frac{x}{j})^j$ is monotonic increasing, so $e^x$ is a dominating function that is integrable. Hence I can apply Lebesgue:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x} dx & = \int_0^{\infty} \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x}dx \\ &= \int_0^{\infty} e^x e^{-\pi x} dx= \int_0^{\infty} e^{(1-\pi) x} dx= - \frac{1}{1-\pi}.
\end{align*}
My colleagues all have a different result though and Wolfram Alpha exceeds computation time. I cannot spot a mistake.

Comment: $\frac 1 {\pi -1}$ is the  correct answer.

Comment: You forgot the $dx$, I added them.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, but first statement
$$
\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^j \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x} dx = 
\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x} dx
$$
needs some clarification:
$$
\int_0^j \left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x} dx = 
\int_0^{+\infty}1_{[0, j]}(x)\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x} dx
$$
where $1_{[0, j]}(x)$ is the indicator function of the set $[0, j]$.
Now you can apply dominated convergence theorem to
$1_{[0, j]}(x)\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^j e^{-\pi x}$.